# The usage of `getClass` method in Scala/Java?

Tags: java, scala, oop, object, classloader

I find this works well (Scala codes)

```
class myClass(i:Int) {

}

val a = new myClass(1)
```

But this doesn't work:

```
val b = a.getClass
val c = new b(1)
```

The compiler will say cannot resolve "b".

Does anyone have ideas about this? 
What are the difference between `b` and `myClass` here?
Does this mean `myClass` is not an object, while `b` is an object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`myClass` is a *type*. `b` is a *value* (or *term*) of type `java.lang.Class`. `new` requires the former kind.

Answer (score 1):

`new` expects a class name in the source code. The compiler will not try to read `b` as an expression that somehow resolves to a class name.

What you seem to be trying to do is reflection: Using an object to describe the class (your `b`) at runtime and getting an instance from that.

Comment: Can you comment on how the above result can be achieved using reflection ?

Comment: You could do `a.getClass.newInstance()` (if there is a no-arg constructor), or in your case `a.getClass.getConstructor(Integer.TYPE).newInstance(1)`